# Selectively Including files in C#.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, include

I am attempting to modify an application with the following characteristics:

- Written in C#.net
- Using Visual Studio 2010
- The application uses a Master sheet to maintain commonality

The Master sheet has the following:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="mysheet.master.cs" Inherits="master_mysheet" %>
```

Now, currently, the master sheet has an include file that brings in a common footer:

```
#include file="inc/my-footer.inc"
```

Here's what I want to do: I would like to modify the master sheet to be able to read in a footer based on the value contained in a session variable... i.e. (not real code, but just something to give an idea of what I want)
    if session("x") = "a" then
     #include file="inc/my-footer1.inc" 
     else
      #include file="inc/my-footer2.inc"

My first instinct was to go with some vbscript:

```
<script type="text/vbscript" language="vbscript">
    document.write("vbscript example.")
</script>
```

However, it doesn't run the vbscript code automatically on page load.

Does anyone know:
- The syntax I need to actually get this to work? i.e. to get the vbscript to run automatically on page load, AND to do the page include?
- Or, is there a better way to go about this? (perhaps by doing some coding in C#)

Note: I am experienced in C#; however, I haven't done any vbscript since the days of ASP classic, so my knowledge there is out of date.

Comment: If I understood correctly - wouldn't `WebUserControl` be appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work?

```
 <% 
 if ("a" == Session["x"]) {
   Html.RenderPartial("a");
 } else {
   Html.RenderPartial("other");
 }
 %>
```

Comment: That actually worked. I did make a small modification... I replaced the 'Html.RenderPartial" with an #include directive.